# Why is String#scan not finding all the matches?

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's use this as sample data :

```
text=<<EOF
#if A==20
        int b = 20;
#else
        int c = 30;
#endif
```

And this code :

```
puts text.scan(/\#.*?\#/m)
```

Why is this only capturing this:

```
#if A==20
    int b = 20;
#
```

I was expecting this to match as well:

```
#else
    int c = 30;
#
```

What do I have to modify so that it captures that as well? I used `/m` for multiline matching, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't match the second part, because the "#" before the else has already been consumed, so all that's left ist

```
else
    int c = 30;
#
```

which does not match the pattern. You can fix this by using lookahead to match the second `#` without consuming it:

```
text.scan(/#.*?(?=#)/m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Second `#` in your input was already matched by the first substring `scan` found. From there, it proceeds to scan the *remaining* part of the string, which is:

```
else
        int c = 30;
#endif
```

which of course doesn't contain anything to match your regex anymore.

Answer (score -1):

`.*?` finds the shortest match. Try just `.*` instead.

Comment: If I don't use `?` I'll only get one match. I'd like 2.